# Proof of orthogonality in a coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

Given any coordinate transformation, how could I prove that the new coordinate system is orthogonal?

Comment: Are you familiar with the dot product?

Comment: Not every coordinate system is orthogonal with respect to the original coordinates.  One test that can be used involves *lengths*, but the exact test depends on what it is you mean by "is orthogonal".  Please use the body of the Question to give a full problem statement (setup and goal), and add some context to give Readers an idea of the level of studies with which you approach this Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that a new system of coordinates is orthogonal you have to find the basis of the new system, made up by the tangent vectors. For ex, if you have new coordinates $u,v$ on the plane and these are related to $x,y$ (Cartesian, orthogonal) coordinates by means of $x=f(u,v)$, $y=g(u,v)$, those new coordinates are orthogonal if the tangent vectors
$$
(\partial f/\partial u,\partial g/\partial u)
$$
and 
$$
(\partial f/\partial v,\partial g/\partial v)
$$

are orthogonal. As a concrete example you can take polar coordinates on the plane $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Polar coordinates are orthogonal (as can be seen geometrically as well).

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonality does not depend on the coordinate system. Are you sure you are not talking about **orthonormal/orthogonal basis** ? To show that a basis of $n$ vectors$\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ is orthogonal you have to show that $v_i \cdot v_j$, the dot product between $v_i$ and $v_j$ is equal to zero if and only if $i = j$

Comment: And if you need an orthonormal basis add to it that $v_i.v_i=1$  $\forall i=1 ... n$